# Remove class with Jquery on a different item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a mobile menu button that has an animation, the class changes on click of the menu and click backs to normal when clicked again. A menu also pops out on click.

I want the animation end state to also click back to normal when I click one of the pop out menu anchor links.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="o-grid__item">
        <button id="menu" class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx">
          <span>toggle menu</span>
        </button>
      </div>enter code here

<nav class="main-menu">   
<ul>

<li>
<a href="#welcome">
<i class="fa"></i>
<span class="nav-text">Home</span>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#portfolio">
<i class="fa"></i>
<span class="nav-text">Work</span>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#about">
<i class="fa"></i>
<span class="nav-text">About</span>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#contact">
<i class="fa"></i>
 <span class="nav-text">Contact</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the script I'm using to toggle the menu

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".c-hamburger").click(function(){
        $(".main-menu").toggleClass("expand-menu");
    });
});
```

Here is the code for the remove/add class for animating the button.

```
(function() {

"use strict";

var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var toggle = toggles[i];
  toggleHandler(toggle);
}; 

function toggleHandler(toggle) {
  toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");
  });
}



})();
```

I need to know how to add remove this class for the menu button, on click of one of my list items in my list? any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to remove a class from an element instead of just toggling it, use the .removeClass extension for the JQuery element selector. Add this to the anchor links

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery anyways, then use this for the class toggling logic

```
$(".main-menu ul li a").click( function(){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("is-active").siblings().removeClass("is-active");
});
```